# Plot Frequency of Values of Multiple Columns

Tags: pandas, plot, count, regression, frequency

I want to create a pandas plot of the frequency of occurrences of values in two columns. The scatter plot is to contain a regression line. The result is a heat map-like plot with a regression line.

Comment: I've posted an answer but I'm hoping for a more pandas like answer for the first three lines. Note I'm asking for a pandas plot answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, combine columns 'A' and 'B' into a unique value. In this case both columns are numeric so I'm using addition. Next use value_counts to create a frequency. Use pandas scatter plot to create the scatter/bubble/heatmap. Finally use numpy.polyfit to drop a regression line.

```
combined = (plotdf['A']*plotdf['B'].nunique()+plotdf['B']) # combine numeric values of columns A and B
vcounts = combined.value_counts() # get value counts of combined values
frequency = combined.map(vcounts) # lookup count for each row
plt = plotdf.plot(x='A',y='B',c=frequency,s=frequency,colormap='viridis',kind='scatter',figsize=(16,8),title='Frequency of A and B')
plt.set(xlabel='A',ylabel='B')
x = plotdf['A'].values
y = plotdf['B'].values
m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1) # requires numpy
plt.plot(x, m*x + b, 'r') # r is color red
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that I've just reinvented a hexbin plot.